# How to check if a particular element is selected or disabled in React Native using Detox?

Tags: react-native, testing, detox

Theres an [accessibilityState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilitystate-android-ios) prop in React Native, I was wondering if there is any way to validate that in detox? or is there any other approach for validating element states?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible, and I’m not sure if at all possible on iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility?language=objc

I don’t see how that state is mapped to the accessibility system on iOS. `UIControl` objects have the `enabled` property, but then again, why would React *Native* actually use native objects. Instead, they implement the wheel and that is not properly exposed.